# Check if a user entered an email address that has a domain similar to the domain name they enter above

Tags: php

In my signup form, I ask users to enter an email with the same domain name as they enter in the url field above.

Right now, I collect data this way:

URL : `http://www.`**domain.com** The domain.com part is what the user enters. The `http://www` is hard coded.

Email : **info**@ **domain.com** The bold part is entered by the user. The **@** is hard coded.

The domain.com part in the url and domain.com part in the email should match. Right now, I can match the two fields since they are separate.

But I want to give up the above approach and make the user enter the entire domain name and email. When that's the case, what would be a good way to check if a user entered an email with the same domain he entered in the url field above.

I'm doing all this using php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php

    //extract domain from email
    $email_domain_temp = explode("@", $_POST['email']);
    $email_domain = $email_domain_temp[1];

    //extract domain from url
    $url_domain_temp = parse_url($_POST['url']);
    $url_domain = strip_out_subdomain($url_domain_temp['host']);

    //compare
    if ($email_domain == $url_domain){
        //match
    }

    function strip_out_subdomain($domain){
        //do nothing if only 1 dot in $domain
        if (substr_count($domain, ".") == 1){
             return $domain;
        }
        $only_my_domain = preg_replace("/^(.*?)\.(.*)$/","$2",$domain);
        return $only_my_domain;
    }
```

So what this does is :

First, split the email string in 2 parts in an array. The second part is the domain.

Second, use the php built in function to parse the url, then extract the "host", while removing the (optionnal) subdomain.

Then compare.

Comment: What if the URL domain doesn't start with www (www2 or meta)? Could you explode the URL_domain_temp['host'] and pass the first array element to str_replace as the first parameter?

Comment: I guess you are right, we have to remove any possible subdomains here.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
supp url = bla@gmail.com
$pieces = explode("@", $url);
$new = $pieces[1]; //which will be gmail.com
```

now again explode

```
$newpc= explode(".", $new );
$new1 = $newpc[0]; //which will be gmail
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my version (tested, works):

```
<?php
$domain = 'www2.example.com'; // Set domain here
$email = 'info@example.com';  // Set email here

if(!preg_match('~^https?://.*$~i', $domain)) { // Does the URL start with http?
    $domain = "http://$domain"; // No, prepend it with http://
}
if(filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) { // Validate URL
    $host = parse_url($domain, PHP_URL_HOST); // Parse the host, if it is an URL
    if(substr_count($host, '.') > 1) { // Is there a subdomain?
        $host = substr($host, -strrpos(strrev($host), '.')); // Get the host
    }
    if(strpos(strrev($email), strrev($host)) === 0) { // Does it match the end of the email?
        echo 'Valid!'; // Valid
    } else {
        echo 'Does not match.'; // Invalid
    }
} else {
    echo 'Invalid domain!'; // Domain is invalid
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url($yourEnteredUrl);
$domainHost = str_replace("www.", "", $parsedUrl["host"]);
$emailDomain = array_pop(explode('@', $yourEnteredEmail));
if( $emailDomain == $domainHost ) {
  //valid data
}
```

Comment: $emailDomain = array_pop(explode('@', $yourEnteredEmail)); returns an error : Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions with positive lookbehinds(i.e only return the expression I'd like to match if it is preceded by a certain pattern, but **don't include** the lookbehind itself in the match), like so:

```
<?php 
$url = preg_match("/(?<=http:\/\/www\.).*/",$_POST['url'],$url_match);
$email = preg_match("/(?<=@).*/",$_POST['email'],$email_match);
if ($url_match[0]==$email_match[0]) {
  // Success Code
 }   
else {
 // Failure Code
     }
?>
```

Of course this is a bit oversimplified as you also need to account for https or www2 and the likes, but these require only minor changes to the RegExp, using the question mark as the "optional" operator

Answer (score 0):

```
$email = 'myemail@example.com';
$site  = 'http://example.com';

$emailDomain = ltrim( strstr($email, '@'), '@' );

// or automate it using array_map(). Syntax is correct only for >= PHP5.4
$cases = ['http://'.$emailDomain, 'https://'.$emailDomain, 'http://www.'.$emailDomain, 'https://www.'.$emailDomain];

$bSameDomain = in_array($site, $cases);
var_dump($bSameDomain);
```

Comment: Erm... for a web-site `http://sb.example.com` with the email `email@sb.example.com` the `$bSameDomain` is `true`

Comment: Your right there... but not for for a web-site http://sb.example.com with the email email@example.com. Depends on what the asker wants i'd say.